# Modelbuilder - Join - Keep matching records only - export to feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export, attribute-joins

I need to join a table to a feature class in a model.  Have it keep only the matching records and then export that joined feature class into a new feature class.

Answer (score 4):

Joins are done in modelbuilder to layers, not feature classes, if you are executing from catalog you must make a feature layer first with [make feature layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000); if you are executing from ArcMap the input should already be a layer. You then join using [Add Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000), leave the *keep all target features* unchecked to just keep the joined features. Then to export I use [copy features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000) which exports to a feature class with all the joined fields. The whole thing looks like this:

[image]

add join dialog here:
[image]

Substitute your own layers and field names... That should do it for you.